# @autowire error with spring-boot, JPA and CrudRepository

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot

I tried to use spring boot with JPA and I got the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accountCommand': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.compta.repositories.AccountRepository com.compta.commands.AccountCommand.accountRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.compta.repositories.AccountRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:648)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:909)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:898)
at Compta.main(Compta.java:12)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.compta.repositories.AccountRepository com.compta.commands.AccountCommand.accountRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.compta.repositories.AccountRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
... 16 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.compta.repositories.AccountRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1103)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:963)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
... 18 more
```

My code :

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Compta {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Compta.class, args);
    }
} 

@Entity
@Table(name = "ACCOUNT")
public class Account {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    public Account() {
        super();
    }

    public long getId() {
     return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Long> {

}

@Service
public class AccountCommand {

    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    public Account create() {
        return accountRepository.save(new Account());
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: If all those classes are in the same package it will work. I'm guessing they are not (so Spring Data doesn't know where to scan for your repository)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at your stack trace it seems that your `Compta` class is not in any package. This can cause problems (see http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference//htmlsingle/#using-boot-using-the-default-package) so I'd try putting all of your classes in a package first.

Also check that your `AccountRepository` is in the same package, or a sub-package of `Compta`.

If you're still having problems, perhaps you can share a complete project that replicates the problem?

Comment: Good answer, I moved the Compta class in a package and everything works.Thank you very much